# Can we simplify the definition of the probability space?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Since the sigma-algebra composes a set of events. And the sample space composes the set of atom events, we can define the probability as function from the sample space to R. This can create a probability space without the sigma-algebra.

The only thing I can think that may make some difference is the definition may impose some unnecessary restrictions on the general definition.

Answer (score 3):

This approach works for a countable set of outcomes that you assign some probabilities with your function, and then compose into events via additivity.

In this case, in the usual formalism, the sigma algebra is just $2^\Omega$... nothing interesting going on.

However, we are interested in uncountable sample spaces. For instance, modeling a continuous random variable like a Gaussian involves uncountably many outcomes. Here it doesn't make sense to assign a probability to each outcome: the probability of the variable taking a given value must be zero.

So when you say "the sample space composes the set of atom events" and then that that's all we need, you are assuming everything can be reduced to atoms. But continuous distributions have no atoms... you need something else in the description to assign probabilities to. This is the role played by the measurable sets in the sigma algebra.

Comment: This is a great answer. I'd add that not only to continuous distributions not have atoms in the sample space, but there are often meaningful limits of discrete atomic processes that cannot themselves be reduced to atoms (e.g. the "end behavior" of a discrete time random walk on $\mathbb Z$).